# How to re-instatiate stavfs output

Tags: python, stat

Why does the last statement fails?

```
>>> import posix
>>> os.statvfs('/boot')
posix.statvfs_result(f_bsize=1024, f_frsize=1024, f_blocks=495844L, f_bfree=412223L, f_bavail=386623L, f_files=128016L, f_ffree=127969L, f_favail=127969L, f_flag=4096, f_namemax=255)
>>> posix.statvfs_result(f_bsize=1024, f_frsize=1024, f_blocks=495844L, f_bfree=412223L, f_bavail=386623L, f_files=128016L, f_ffree=127969L, f_favail=127969L, f_flag=4096, f_namemax=255)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: structseq() takes at most 2 arguments (10 given)
```

The "system" asks that I explain why my problem is different than some potential duplicate. It is not so much that my problem is that different, it's just that I find that providing a direct solution here is better for pragmatic reasons: the answer to the other question doesn't clearly establish what is happening and, in doing so, keeps the scope of the answer narrow and more difficult to generalize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [structseq() error with time.struct\_time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551514/structseq-error-with-time-struct-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the duplicate suggestion I was able to transpose its solution to my problem.

Changing

```
posix.statvfs_result(f_bsize=1024, f_frsize=1024, f_blocks=495844L, f_bfree=412223L, f_bavail=386623L, f_files=128016L, f_ffree=127969L, f_favail=127969L, f_flag=4096, f_namemax=255)
```

to

```
posix.statvfs_result((1024, 1024, 495844L, 412223L, 386623L, 128016L, 127969L, 127969L, 4096, 255))
```

solves my problem:

```
>>> posix.statvfs_result((1024, 1024, 495844L, 412223L, 386623L, 128016L, 127969L, 127969L, 4096, 255))
posix.statvfs_result(f_bsize=1024, f_frsize=1024, f_blocks=495844L, f_bfree=412223L, f_bavail=386623L, f_files=128016L, f_ffree=127969L, f_favail=127969L, f_flag=4096, f_namemax=255)
```

So to make this more complete and convenient, here is how converting to tuple allows recreating the results of `os.statvfs`:

```
>>> tuple(os.statvfs('/boot'))
(1024, 1024, 495844L, 412223L, 386623L, 128016L, 127969L, 127969L, 4096, 255)
>>> posix.statvfs_result(tuple(os.statvfs('/boot')))
posix.statvfs_result(f_bsize=1024, f_frsize=1024, f_blocks=495844L, f_bfree=412223L, f_bavail=386623L, f_files=128016L, f_ffree=127969L, f_favail=127969L, f_flag=4096, f_namemax=255)
```